# closed due to error connection error - minecraft server using tunneling with playit.gg

Tags: networking, minecraft, tunneling

i’ve been getting an error when my `minecraft` server crashes. It’s using a service called `playit.g`g that utilizes tunneling to make it so you don’t have to use port forwarding.

Error thrown:

```
{random ip} /tcp tunnel=>host: closed due to error: Error { kind: Io(Kind(BrokenPipe)) }, mapping: tunnel=>host, client_addr: {random ip}, version: 0.4.6
```

If someone can help i would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Creator of [playit.gg](https://playit.gg) here. This error happens when the connection from the playit program to the game running on your PC has been closed. It makes sense this happens when your Minecraft server crashes and the "host" server is no longer available.

I'd recommend updating playit if you haven't already. We're now on version 0.8.3-beta. https://playit.gg/download